# javascript display multiple images

Tags: javascript, image

Just to let you know I am a complete newbie,
I have  a html page that shows different images combined. I am using javascript to select images to display.
Here's my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num1 = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 6 );
var num2 = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 6 );
var num3 = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 6 );
var num4 = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 6 );
var num5 = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 4 );
var imgpath1 = "<img src=" + '"'  ;
var imgpath2= "./Nums24-38/Nums" + num5 + "_";
var imgpath3= ".png" + '"' ;
var imgpathA =  imgpath1  + imgpath2 + num1 + imgpath3   ;
var imgpathB =  imgpath1  + imgpath2 + num2 + imgpath3   ;
var imgpathC =  imgpath1  + imgpath2 + num3 + imgpath3   ;
var imgpathD =  imgpath1  + imgpath2 + num4 + imgpath3   ;
var imgpathE = imgpathA + imgpathB + imgpathC + imgpathD ;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello </h1>
<h2>Welcome to Home-brewed Captcha </h2>

My Random number is <script>document.write(num1);    document.write(num2);     document.write(num3);document.write(num4)</script> 

<p> My path is <script>document.write(imgpath2); document.write(num1); document.write(imgpath3) </script></p>

<p>First Java Image is <script>document.write(imgpathA) </script> </p>

<p>Second Java Image is <script>document.write(imgpathB) </script> </p>

<p>Third Java Image is <script>document.write(imgpathC) </script> </p>

<p>Fourth Java Image is <script>document.write(imgpathD) </script> </p>


<p> Merged Java Image ABCD is 
<script> document.write(imgpathA) </script> 
<script> document.write(imgpathB) </script> 
<script> document.write(imgpathC) </script> 
<script> document.write(imgpathD) </script> 
</p>


<p> New merged Java image A+B+C+D is<script>document.write(imgpathE)     </script> </p>

<h3>Another merge , this time bypassing java <img src="./Nums24-38/Nums3_3.png"><img src="./Nums24-38/Nums3_1.png"><img src="./Nums24-38/Nums3_0.png"><img src="./Nums24-38/Nums3_6.png"></h3>
</body>
```

You can see a live demo at http://sopariwala.ca/1.html
Why does all images dont show up.
Where am I going wrong.
Muja

Answer (score 0):

Simple... You are using `document.write()` incorrectly!

```
str = 'abcd.png'
dcument.write(str)

// result is:
// abcd.png
```

All you are doing is 'writing' the url of the image to the page.

Try this if you must, though I don't reccomend it over inserting the tags outright:

```
document.write('<img src="abcd.png"/>')
```